# JSON Parsing in android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I have an url and I parse json content using `JsonParser` class. I want to display images from webservice. When I use json object for parsing data then I can't get value and error is display in logcat (`JsonException`):

```
public String PostConnection(String strUrl,ArrayList<NameValuePair> alstNameValuePair) {
            InputStream mInputStream = null;
            try {
                //This is the default apacheconnection.
                HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //          HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(mHttpClient.getParams(), 60000); //Timeout Limit
                //Pathe of serverside 
    //          HttpPost mHttpPost = new HttpPost(strUrl);
                HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(strUrl);

    //          if(alstNameValuePair!=null)
    //          { 
                    //post the valur you want to pass.
    //               mHttpGet.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(alstNameValuePair));
    //          }

                //get the valu from the saerverside as response.
                HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
                HttpEntity mHttpEntity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
                mInputStream = mHttpEntity.getContent();

              } 
              catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

             String strLine = null;
             String strResult = "";

            //convert response in to the string.
            try {
                    if(mInputStream!=null){
                      BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream,HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
                      StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                      while((strLine = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        mStringBuilder.append(strLine + "\n");
                      }
                          strResult = mStringBuilder.toString();
                          mInputStream.close();
                    }
               } 
               catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             return strResult;
        }
```

And Here is my `MainActivity.java` class code

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> mNameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                mNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_product", "id_product"));
                Log.i("NameValuePair","" + mNameValuePair);
                JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
                result = jparser.PostConnection(URL1, null);
                Log.i("result",""+ result);

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put(result, true);
                Log.i("JSON FROM URL","" +  json);

    //          String jb = json.get("id_product").toString();
    //          Log.i("jb string","" + jb);


                JSONArray jArray = json.names();
                Log.i("JSON ARRAY","" + jArray);

                String jb = jArray.get(0).toString();
                Log.i("jb string","" + jb);
                ArrayList<String> ararylst = new ArrayList<String>();
                ararylst.add(result);
                Log.i("ArrayList for result",""+ ararylst);


                for(int i=0;i<=jArray.length();i++){

                    Log.i("Json Length",""+ jArray.length());
    //              JSONObject jo = json.getJSONObject("image");
    //              Log.i("JSON OBject in for",""+ jo);
    //              image = jo.getString("image");
    //              Log.i("String in for",""+ image);
    //              json.get("image");
                    JSONObject tableData = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    image = tableData.getString("image");
                    Log.i("imageinloop",""+ image);
                    arraylist.add(image);
                    Log.i("ArrayList","" +arraylist);

    //              AddObjectToList(image);

                }

            }
             catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is my Json

```
[
    {
        "id_product": "4549",
        "product_code": "9788184402070",
        "id_author": "70",
        "image": "iblazing.net/navbharat/img/p/9/0/9/7/9097-tonytheme_product.jpg"
  },

 {
        "id_product": "4550",
        "product_code": "9788184402071",
        "id_author": "71",
        "image": "iblazing.net/navbharat/img/p/9/0/9/7/9097-tonytheme_product1.jpg"
  }
]
```

Here is my Logcat Error:

```
11-12 06:04:59.072: W/System.err(2748): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id_product":"4549","product_code":"9788184402070","id_author":"70","id_editor":"70","id_translator":"70","id_supplier":"0","id_booklang":"1","id_baseunit":"0","id_distributor":"1","id_publisher":"1","id_manufacturer":"0","id_category_default":"2","id_shop_default":"1","id_tax_rules_group":"1","on_sale":"0","online_only":"0","ean13":"","upc":"","ecotax":"0.000000","quantity":"-1","minimal_quantity":"1","price":"135.000000","wholesale_price":"0.000000","unity":"","unit_price_ratio":"0.000000","additional_shipping_cost":"0.00","reference":"","supplier_reference":"","location":"","width":"0.000000","height":"0.000000","depth":"0.000000","weight":"0.000000","out_of_stock":"2","quantity_discount":"0","customizable":"0","uploadable_files":"0","text_fields":"0","active":"1","redirect_type":"404","id_product_redirected":"0","available_for_order":"1","available_date":"0000-00-00","condition":"new","show_price":"1","indexed":"1","visibility":"both","cache_is_pack":"0","cache_has_attachments":"0","is_virtual":"0","cache_default_attribute":"0","no_of_pages":"224","bindingtype":"paper","upcoming":"0","booktype":"ebook","date_add":"2013-10-16 15:23:46","date_upd":"2013-10-25 14:13:54","advanced_stock_management":"0","id_shop":"1","id_product_attribute":null,"description":"<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong><span>\u00a0is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<\/span><\/p>","description_short":"<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong>\u00a0is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<\/p>","description_guj":"<p>\u0aaa\u0ab0\u0acd\u0ab5\u0aa4\u0aae\u0abe\u0ab3\u0abe\u0aa8\u0ac0 \u0a85\u0a82\u0aa6\u0ab0 \u0aaa\u0acd\u0ab0\u0ab5\u0ac7\u0ab6\u0ac7 \u0a9b\u0ac7 \u0aa4\u0ac7\u0ab5\u0abe\u0a82 \u0aac\u0ab9\u0ac1 \u0aa5\u0acb\u0aa1\u0abe\u0a82 \u0ab8\u0acd\u0aa5\u0ab3\u0acb\u0aae\u0abe\u0a82\u0aa8\u0abe \u0a8f\u0a95 \u0ab5\u0abe\u0a9f\u0ac7 \u0a85\u0aae\u0ac7 \u0aa4\u0abf\u0aac\u0ac7\u0a9f\u0aae\u0abe\u0a82 \u0aa6\u0abe\u0a96\u0ab2 \u0aa5\u0aaf\u0abe \u0ab9\u0aa4\u0abe. \u0a86 \u0ab5\u0a96\u0aa4\u0ac7 \u0a85\u0aae\u0ac7 \u0a86\u0a97\u0ab3 \u0a95\u0ac7\u0a9f\u0ab2\u0ac7 \u0ab8\u0ac1\u0aa7\u0ac0 \u0a9c\u0a88 \u0ab6\u0a95\u0ab6\u0ac1\u0a82 \u0aa4\u0ac7\u0aa8\u0ac0 \u0a9a\u0abf\u0a82\u0aa4\u0abe, \u0a85\u0ab2\u0aac\u0aa4\u0acd\u0aa4, \u0ab9\u0ab5\u0ac7 \u0a85\u0aae\u0aa8\u0ac7 \u0aa5\u0ab5\u0abe \u0ab2\u0abe\u0a97\u0ac0. \u0ab8\u0abe\u0ab0\u0ac7 \u0aa8\u0ab8\u0ac0\u0aac\u0ac7 \u0a85\u0ab9\u0ac0\u0a82 \u0a85\u0aae\u0aa8\u0ac7 \u0a95\u0acb\u0a88 \u0a93\u0ab3\u0a96\u0aa4\u0ac1\u0a82 \u0aa8\u0ab9\u0acb\u0aa4\u0ac1\u0a82, \u0aa8\u0ac7 \u0a95\u0acb\u0a88 \u0a9d\u0ac7\u0ab0\u0ac0\u0ab2\u0abe \u0a85\u0aae\u0ab2\u0aa6\u0abe\u0ab0\u0ac7 \u0ab2\u0acb\u0a95\u0acb\u0aa8\u0ac7 \u0a85\u0aae\u0abe\u0ab0\u0abe\u0aa5\u0ac0 \u0aad\u0aa1\u0a95\u0abe\u0ab5\u0ac7\u0ab2\u0abe \u0aaa\u0aa3 \u0aa8\u0ab9\u0acb\u0aa4\u0abe. \u0a95\u0acb\u0a88 \u0aaa\u0ac2\u0a9b\u0aaa\u0ab0\u0a9b \u0a95\u0ab0\u0aa4\u0ac1\u0a82, \u0aa4\u0acb \u0a85\u0aae\u0ac7 \u0a95\u0ab9\u0ac7\u0aa4\u0abe \u0a95\u0ac7 \u0a95\u0ac8\u0ab2\u0abe\u0ab8\u0aa8\u0ac0 \u0a9c\u0abe\u0aa4\u0acd\u0ab0\u0abe\u0a8f \u0aa8\u0ac0\u0a95\u0ab3\u0acd\u0aaf\u0abe \u0a9b\u0ac0\u0a8f<\/p>","description_short_guj":"<p>\u0aaa\u0ab0\u0acd\u0ab5\u0aa4\u0aae\u0abe\u0ab3\u0abe\u0aa8\u0ac0 \u0a85\u0a82\u0aa6\u0ab0 \u0aaa\u0acd\u0ab0\u0ab5\u0ac7\u0ab6\u0ac7 \u0a9b\u0ac7 \u0aa4\u0ac7\u0ab5\u0abe\u0a82 \u0aac\u0ab9\u0ac1 \u0aa5\u0acb\u0aa1\u0abe\u0a82 \u0ab8\u0acd\u0aa5\u0ab3\u0acb\u0aae\u0abe\u0a82\u0aa8\u0abe \u0a8f\u0a95 \u0ab5\u0abe\u0a9f\u0ac7 \u0a85\
11-12 06:04:59.072: W/System.err(2748):  at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-12 06:04:59.081: W/System.err(2748):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
11-12 06:04:59.081: W/System.err(2748):     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
11-12 06:04:59.081: W/System.err(2748):     at app.navbharatpublication.tablet.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:549)
11-12 06:04:59.081: W/System.err(2748):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-12 06:04:59.091: W/System.err(2748):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-12 06:04:59.091: W/System.err(2748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-12 06:04:59.091: W/System.err(2748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-12 06:04:59.091: W/System.err(2748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-12 06:04:59.091: W/System.err(2748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-12 06:04:59.091: W/System.err(2748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 06:04:59.103: W/System.err(2748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 06:04:59.111: W/System.err(2748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-12 06:04:59.111: W/System.err(2748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 06:04:59.111: W/System.err(2748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 06:04:59.111: W/System.err(2748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-12 06:04:59.121: W/System.err(2748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-12 06:04:59.121: W/System.err(2748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is your error in logcat ? please post it.

Comment: Your method is returning String not JsonObject.

Comment: Where you get the error.just post the log cat details.

Comment: what i can do for this?

Comment: You have simply the array in your json response. So you just have to parse the array using jsonObject only.

Comment: i get json in string result but how i can get value of "image"?

Comment: @GrlsHu, i get json in string result and that result is put as JSONObject json.Now this json parse in jsonarray will get ["[{\"id_product\":\"4549\"}]"] Is this right way?

Comment: No this is wrong way. Because you are only getting JSONObjects in a single array only. So you have to access your each values using jsonobject only.

Comment: @user2009847, thanks i got result.

Comment: how to display images using above josn in dynamically created imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
         JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put(result, true);
            Log.i("JSON FROM URL","" +  json);
```

Instead, you should do something like:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
```

After that, you preceed with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject product = json.getJSONObject(i);
    String image = product.getString("image");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There server is returning a

> JSONArray []

and you are trying to build

> JSONObject {}

Use JSONArray to parse response and you can then proceed further to look out for other errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

To parse

```
  JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
           JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);        
           Log.v("result--", c.getString("image"));

   }
```